# Method [validateA] does not exist in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel

[image]im trying to validate a set of fields and i get this error, i tried google,laracast but to no help
Here is my controller

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function add_banner_submit()
{
     $data= Input::except(array('_token'));
     $rule = array(
                'uname'=>'required',
                'image'=>'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|required',
                'url'=>'required',
              );
    $validator = Validator::make($rule,$data);
    if ($validator->fails()) {

            return view('siteadmin.add_banner');
    } else {
           $inputs=Input::all();
           $entry=array(
                   'uname'=>Input::get('uname'),
                   'image'=>Input::get('image'),
                   'url'=>Input::get('url')
                  );

          Banner::add_banner_submit($entry);
          echo"success";
          return view('siteadmin.add_banner');
     }
}
```

**what could be the issue,? Any help is appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line-

```
$validator = Validator::make($rule,$data);
```

To this-

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rule);
```

Comment: i found out anyways tankx @Sohel0415

Comment: congrats then :)

Answer (score 1):

haha actually the Solution was simple,i just had to interchange

```
$validator = Validator::make($data,$rule);
```

to this then it worked ,the validator was referencing to the rule first before data so i got the error